# Paytm delegate issue, App crashes due to delegate not set

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, paytm

App is crashing, reason on crash is

> 'No delegate set?...how are you going to callbacks?'

Delegate for PGTransactionViewController is set. But still its not calling the delegate method.

```
        PGTransactionViewController *txnController = [[PGTransactionViewController alloc]
                                                  initTransactionForOrder:pgOrder];
#if SERVER_PRODUCTION
    txnController.serverType = eServerTypeProduction;
#else
    txnController.serverType = eServerTypeStaging;
#endif

    txnController.merchant = [PGMerchantConfiguration defaultConfiguration];

    // Set the Delegates
    txnController.delegate = self;
    [self.hostViewController.navigationController pushViewController:txnController animated:YES];
```

The class is subclass of NSObject.

Comment: Did you conform to protocol?

Comment: Yeah i have conformed to this protocol. <PGTransactionDelegate>

Answer (score 0):

Are you using these delegate methods?

```
  - (void)didSucceedTransaction:(PGTransactionViewController *)controller
                     response:(NSDictionary *)response
{
    DEBUGLOG(@"ViewController::didSucceedTransactionresponse= %@", response);

}

- (void)didFailTransaction:(PGTransactionViewController *)controller error:(NSError *)error response:(NSDictionary *)response
{
    DEBUGLOG(@"ViewController::didFailTransaction error = %@ response= %@", error, response);

}

- (void)didCancelTransaction:(PGTransactionViewController *)controller error:(NSError*)error response:(NSDictionary *)response
{
    DEBUGLOG(@"ViewController::didCancelTransaction error = %@ response= %@", error, response);

}

- (void)didFinishCASTransaction:(PGTransactionViewController *)controller response:(NSDictionary *)response
{
    DEBUGLOG(@"ViewController::didFinishCASTransaction:response = %@", response);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I am using the same delegate methods except the last one.

Comment: in my code delgate are not calling on success and cancelled

Comment: in my case none of these delegate calls after transaction is done. Nothing is called after success/failed/cancel. What to do??